# git push with post-receive slow

Tags: git, push, git-post-receive

My git push operation finishes in around 25-30 seconds, instead of (more-or-less) immediate return.
I am using a quite long post-receive (bash) script that I`ve found here: https://raw.github.com/zma/usefulscripts/master/script/post-receive

Some details:

- my remote repository is on a LAN server, where we have around 70MB/s read/write access (this looks okay)
- this is a fresh repository with only 1 single test file in it
- I am using the git bash, installed by gitextension (git version 1.7.11.msysgit.1)
- I also tested a push operation with gitgui, but the delay was the same. So I think it is not related to the frontend I am using.
- if I remove the post-receive script, push operation works okay (no delay at all)

I did some testing and if the post-receive script contains around 70 lines that are all commented out (so the script does nothing), push has a delay around 5 seconds.

Is this normal?
Or is there a way to speed up push? 
Or I must reduce the script size dramatically?

**Update:**
It is important to mention that:

- I am using windows7
- the remote repository is hosted on a linux server, reachable through samba

Answer (score 2):

An interesting follow up:
I`ve tested the script on another PC and it is working fine. No delay at all. So there are some issues on my PC regarding how git processes remote scripts.

The remote repository is on a samba share. I took a wireshark traces with 2 scenarios:

1. just executed `cat <path_to_the_script>\post-receive` command in the git bash
2. did a `real` git push

Results (without too much technical details):

1. Read AndX Request, FID: 0x228f, 1024 bytes at offset 0 (1024 bytes at time, always)
2. Read AndX Request, FID: 0x21c9, 1 byte at offset 0 (1 byte, always)

Conclusion:
git push command reads the post-receive script in 1 byte chunks

Comment: My reply is not an answer, as I still don`t know why git processes the post-receive script slowly. I just added it as `answer` instead of a `comment`, as you cannot do normal formatting in a `comment`.

Answer (score 1):

The [git hooks page](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) clearly mentions about the `post-receive` hook:

> This script can’t stop the push process, but the client doesn’t disconnect until it has completed; so, be careful when you try to do anything that may take a long time.

That means, in your case, you need to switch to an asynchronous approach (unless you can fix what takes time, like [Sqeezer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587574/sqeezer)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17059190/6309), upvoted, seems to propose):

- making your script write in a file what it is supposed to do (send email)
- letting a cron job pick up on that file and perform the lengthy task every few minutes.

That way, the post-receive hook returns as fast as possible, not blocking the client (downstream repo from where the push was initiated)

Comment: This is also a good tip, but I have tested this also (or something similar): I`ve modified the script to skip the mail sending process (skip also the temporary file creation for the email body), and just gather the information (who did what on what branch), delay was around 15-20 seconds. But I have a feeling that the real reason of being a bit faster without the mail sending is that there are less lines in the script to process, and not because the script itself has less things to do.

Comment: @user2448122 so you could follow that tip, with a one-line hook script collecting the information and writing it to a file, while the cron job script contains the bulk of the process ;)

Answer (score 1):

From the script description

```
# An example hook script to mail out commit update information.  This hook
# sends emails listing new revisions to the repository introduced by the
# change being reported.  The rule is that (for branch updates) each commit
# will appear on one email and one email only.
```

Then take a look at the bottom of the script. It says:

```
# Note: change the smtp server to yours
        cat $email_tmp_file | mailx -S smtp="smtp://smtp.cse.ust.hk" -s "$emailsubject" -r $senderemail $recipients
```

I believe you haven't configured your smtp server, therefore your script is waiting for `smtp.cse.ust.hk` to connect and then just disconnects by timeout.

Comment: Good tip, but fortunately I was also reading the description :). So I have changed the smtp server config for our own before I started to test. And again, if there is nothing in the script just commented out lines, the push is delayed with ~5 seconds. So it must be something about parsing the post-receive script`s text.

Comment: I don't think that the issue in the script itself, because it's just bash script and it has fair performance on Unix platforms. Have you ever tried to run the script manually form command line?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the samba share was configured to not to use oplocks with the following options in the smb.conf:

- oplock = No
- level2 oplocks = No

Removing these entries from the share`s configuration reduced the delay of the post-receive execution to around 4-5 seconds, which is reasonable I think.

Comment: Excellent. +1. Good to know. No need for my "asynchronous" approach I mentioned in my answer, then.